# The infinite sum of bounded sequence is bound, is the sequence convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $f(x)$ be a lower bounded scalar-valued function where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and we have the following:

$$
f(x_{k})-f(x_{k+1}) \geq \frac{l}{2} ||x_k-x_{k+1}||^2 , \quad \forall k\geq 0 \text{ and }  \exists l>0
$$

Therefore, one can write $ \frac{l}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{k} ||x_i-x_{i+1}||^2 \leq f(x_{0})-f(x_{k+1})$ where the right hand side of the inequality is bounded. If we let $k$ go to infinity we have the following:
$$
\frac{l}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} ||x_i-x_{i+1}||^2 \leq \text{bounded}
$$

**Questions**:

1- Why can one say $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}||x_k-x_{k+1}||^2=0$?

2- Why $\{f(x_k)\}_{k\geq 0}$ is convergent?

Comment: I would assume that the actual quantification is $\exists l>0,\forall k\ge0$.

Comment: Suppose it wasn't zero for a contradiction. Then you would have an infinite sum of non negative numbers which can't be bounded

Comment: @R. Maresca: Please writ this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}|| x_k - x_{k+1} || ^2 = \varepsilon > 0$. Then $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty ||x_i - x_{i+1} ||^2 \geq \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \eta$ where $\eta$ is any number less than $\varepsilon$ and greater than $0$. But this is a contradiction as you've already shown that the sum is bounded.

Comment: Can you please provide an answer for the second question?

Comment: It follows from the fact that it is a decreasing sequence bounded below, hence must converge.